# How to render a View at specific coordinates of the page?

Tags: react-native

When the screen is touched and hold at a certain position, I would like to render a `View` exactly where the screen is touched( like context menu in android). I have page coordinates `pageX` and `pageY`, And I would like to render a `View` according to these coordinates.

Is there any way to give these coordinates in Style object as shown below,

```
<View style={{X: 120, Y: 75}} />
```

Comment: So you basically want something like `position: fixed` as in regular css?

Comment: @dentemm  I don't want to fix it some where, But want to render where ever I touch the screen. Usually any component can be rendered where ever we want by using padding and margin. But is there any way to render by specifying coordinates of the page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike regular CSS, react-native does not support `position: fixed` to manually position a view on a certain position relative to the viewport. But you could use a workaround with `position: 'absolute'` and the `onLayout` method of the parent component. I will try to clarify:

**Step 1:**

Let's assume you have a parent view which is exactly the width and height of your screen, then you could easily position the view like so:

```js
<View> // this parent view has the same dimensions as the screen
  // Below is the view you want to position according your x, y coordinates
  <View 
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      left: this.state.x,
      top: this.state.y
    }}>
  </View>
</View>
```

**Step 2 (optional):**

The touch coordinates you have are screen coordinates, so step 1 isn't sufficient if your view isn't exactly the same size as your screen. But react-native provides a `measureInWindow()` (available through a component's ref) callback to determine a component 's screen coordinates.

So basically you call `measureInWindow()` on the parent view whenever a touch takes place to determine the x and y offset of the parent window and you take this offset into account to calculate the correct x and y values.

Answer (score 1):

With `getBoundingClientRect()` DOM component method you can get information about the geometry of the object and position. Then, with `currentTranslate` object attribute, you can translate it to the desired place.

For example, imagine you have a button at position (100, 100) and you want to move it to (300, 300). With the first method, you would get the actual position and with currentTranslate(200, 200) you would be able to move it to (300, 300), like that:
`element.currentTranslate = {x: 200, y: 200}`

Maybe there is better way but I know this one works :D

I hope it helps

Comment: Can I specify like `style={{element.currentTranslate = {x: 200, y: 200}}}` or Can you tell me how to provide this to a `View`

Comment: It is nothing related to style. You have to work with the Ref of the component

Comment: Neither `TouchableOpacity` nor `View` contains `currentTranslate` . Can you tell me where I can get this method?